# Can Fluent NHibernate support all mappings from NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I want to use Fluent NHibernate with NHibernate. But I want to find out whether Fluent NHibernate support all mappings from NHbernate. Or is it better to stick with NHibernate?

Answer (score 4):

**Fluent NHibernate** supports **automappings**, **standard nhibernate xml mappings (hbm)** and of course **Fluent** style mappings. You can mix and match any of those mappings with Fluent NHibernate.

Fluent does not support the new **mapping by code** style introduced in version 3.2 (they're really different animals) of NHibernate but I'm not sure that this is really an issue.  Personally I would recommend using Fluent at this point because there is far more documentation and the user base is larger than **mapping by code**.

**Fluent NHibernate** is fairly easy to use and definitely has it's advantages over xml style (hbm) mappings.  You can read about this more on the [Fluent Wiki](http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Getting_started#Configuration)

Answer (score 0):

just FYI; I tried using standard hbm.xml for mapping "many-to-any" which is currently not supported by fluent nhibernate;

tried both Configuration.AddXmlFile and HbmMappings

both still failed with error message saying invalid properties "many to any"